# Geoviews Attribute error: module 'geoviews' has no attribute 'output'

Tags: python, attributeerror, geoviews

I just installed [GeoViews](http://geo.holoviews.org/) with success and I tried to follow one example at the first page of their site and this already gave me an error. In fact, there are two errors of the same type that occurred to me. The first:

```py
import geoviews as gv
import geoviews.feature as gf
import xarray as xr
from cartopy import crs

gv.extension('bokeh', 'matplotlib')
```

The last command gives me this:

```py
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-7a99f49a6c24> in <module>
----> 1 gv.extension('bokeh', 'matplotlib')

AttributeError: module 'geoviews' has no attribute 'extension'
```

Which is odd since it is the very first command line of their tutorial. The second thing I tried was their second example (the second image in the site)

```py
dataset = gv.Dataset(xr.open_dataset('./data/ensemble.nc'))
ensemble = dataset.to(gv.Image, ['longitude', 'latitude'], 'surface_temperature')

gv.output(ensemble.opts(cmap='viridis', colorbar=True, fig_size=200, backend='matplotlib') * gf.coastline(),
          backend='matplotlib')
```

I used a different file and everything went well until the last line where, again, I got an attribute error.

```py
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-ee9535e372cb> in <module>
      3 ensemble = dataset.to(gv.Image)
      4 
----> 5 gv.output(ensemble.opts(cmap='viridis', colorbar=True, fig_size=200, backend='matplotlib') * gf.coastline(),
      6           backend='matplotlib')

AttributeError: module 'geoviews' has no attribute 'output'
```

How can geoviews give these errors? How can I fix it?

Answer (score 2):

The correct install command is `conda install -c pyviz geoviews`. We've now removed the old copy that was left on the `ioam` channel, to prevent this problem from happening to others.

-- The GeoViews team

Answer (score 1):

I just figured out what was the problem. I followed the [anaconda install command](https://anaconda.org/ioam/geoviews) which gave me an older version of Geoviews. The updated version can be found in [this link](https://github.com/pyviz/geoviews) and can be installed with the command

```
conda install -c pyviz geoviews
```